# await doesn't wait for rest response C# .netCore

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, restsharp

I have a client that has to make consecutive rest calls, the rest call will execute some functionality and has a state. in parallel to running the rest call, the client should poll the server every few seconds to check on the status of the process on the server side (to check if the server finished with the functionality that was executing as a result of the original rest call.

The client has the following calls:

```
 await runMultiScan(scanId, exitActions);
 handleExitActions(exitActions);
```

and `runMultiScan` is implemented the following way:

```
    private async Task runMultiScan(Guid scanId, List<Action> exitActions)
    {                        
       var client = new RestClient(baseURL);

        var request = new RestRequest(@"api/scans", Method.POST);
        request.AddJsonBody(new Scan
        {
            sid = scanId.ToString(),
            scanPath = scansParentPath

        });
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
```

In parallel I have getStatus function which also makes a rest call to the server.
The strange thing is after the rest call in "runMultiScan" takes a few minutes, it exits the await and goes to `handleExitActions(exitActions);`

Altough the server hasn't reached the completion of the RestRequest:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] ScanData scanInfo)
    {

       currentScan = new Scan(scanInfo);
      currentScan.runScan();                       

    }
```

and the process on the server is still inside the runScan and hasn't returned.
What can be the reason for this behavior (await not waiting for Post to finish)?

Comment: Its a good idea to add 'Async' to method names that return a Task, as it helps spot little bugs in async/await code. What does runScan() return or do? Why pass exitActions into the function when it doesn't use them?

Comment: not sure, bit if I remember correctly, RestClient class has default timeout set to 100 seconds? So function on server takes more than 100s, RestClient timeouts so that should be it. Check on server what is wrong, potential deadlock...?

Comment: runScan returns void and does some scanning operation of the code

Comment: timeout seems logical.

Comment: Do you control the api you are calling? Have a test with something like https://reqres.in/ to see if you even get a response back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, bit if I remember correctly, RestClient class has default timeout set to 100 seconds? So function on server takes more than 100s, RestClient timeouts so that should be it. Check on server what is wrong, potential deadlock...?